# .env Environment variables not being used

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am trying to deploy my react web app to Firebase. I have a github workflow setup in order to deploy to a preview channel when pull request is created, and then when it is merged it will deploy that to be live. I have my firebase api key and other details stored in a .env file, which is in my .gitignore as to not check that into the git repository. However, these variables are not being used when the app is deployed to firebase. A blank page is displayed and an error in the console saying that an incorrect API key is being used and to please use correct api key. However, if I hardcode the exact same value into the config for firebase directly, it works without any issue. Any ideas on how to fix this? The .env example and how I am using it is below. (without the actual values in .env file of course). Also, the .env file is in the root of the project as well.

.env sample:

```
REACT_APP_API_KEY={{value}}
REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN={{value}}
REACT_APP_DATABASE_URL={{value}}
REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID={{value}}
REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET={{value}}
REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID={{value}}
```

firebase.js

```
const config = {
apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_DATABASE_URL,
projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
};
```

Comment: Did you import dotenv into your project?

Comment: From my understanding, all that is needed is to have .env file in the root of the project, and then start each key with REACT_APP_ and they will be accessible through process.env.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm having the same touble

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should add `.production` at the end of the `.env` filename. It becomes `.env.production`,then build and deploy.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have tried this, however, it does not work as well. I currently have tried three scenarios, none of them working. I have a .env.development and .env.production files. I have tried with just a single .env file, and then tried with all three of those. None of these have worked successfully.